# Why does my render result look different than the rendered preview in the 3D view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, compositing-nodes

This is the rendered preview.
[image]

This is the render result.
[image]

I tried to increase the sample size but the problem persists. I want the render to look like the rendered preview.

Comment: Could you explain which rendered elements are different than expected? The geometry, the colors, the aberation/lens distorsion, ... ?

Comment: @Leander Sorry for the lack of detail. The rendered result is expected to look like the image I newly uploaded.

Comment: That distorsion and aberation must be caused by some sort of postprocessing. Have you added any compositing nodes? If you added them unintentionally uncheck the [compositing box](https://imgur.com/a/8CFCMtQ) before rendering to ignore the compositing setup and render  it as it is seen in the viewport. In may still help **describing** the difference of your results and expectation in words as well as you can.

Comment: I unchecked the compositing box and now it renders normally. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: Great, I have added an answer for completeness. You can accept it, if it helped solve your problem or edit it if you would like to add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an active [compositing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/introduction.html) step. To disable all compositing, uncheck the Compositing checkbox under Post Processing in the Properties Area.

[image]

Compositing alters the image after it is rendered, it is set up in [node editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/node_editor/introduction.html#interface). You could also delete all compositing [nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/output/composite.html), alternatively to turning compositing off.